# Application crash dump

Tags: windows-10, crash, event-log

I have an app that that periodically crashes on our corporate Windows 10 build server (where the product is built from sources with MSVC and tested). I found the following in Windows Event Log:

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.6.0.3245, time stamp: 0x650974de
Faulting module name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.6.0.3245, time stamp: 0x650974de
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000051cd0
Faulting process id: 0x4c30
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9eaeabaf8a16e
Faulting application path: C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\...
Faulting module path: C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\...\MyApp.exe
Report Id: 50c971eb-e126-4a05-ad73-b56a570a7abe
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Where can I find crash dumps that contain the stack trace?

`MyApp.exe` is run as system user while performing automatic integration tests on this Windows 10 machine.

Comment: If your application doesn't have logging baked in using log4net for example, then there won't be a log. If you have .pdb's with your dll's, they may add some insight. But as-is, you likely won't have anything more to view than the event viewer event shared in your question.

Comment: @spikey_richie There is a folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps` where the crash dumps are created for regular users, I need the same for system user.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no crash dumps for "system".   What crash dumps I have here are not particularly helpful either.

Comment: You might see if you can capture the issue SysInternals ProcMon and capture a file of the event(s).

Comment: A crash dump is not always created. // The documentation says this: “For example, the profile folder for System services is %WINDIR%\System32\Config\SystemProfile. For Network and Local Services, the folder is %WINDIR%\ServiceProfiles”. Have you checked those folders yet? // (I also ___strongly___ suggest you set up a separate regular user for your GitLab Runner.)

Comment: What would a crash dump help if you already know which is the application that is crashing on illegal address exception?

Comment: @harrymc it sounds a bit strage, or probably I misunderstand something, the question sounds like "What are crash dumps for?"